# Removing object added in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uicollectionview

If I want to release my `UICollectionView` in `UIViewController` from code, is setting

```
self.typeCollectionView = nil;
```

enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 
You have to remove it from view hierarchy by calling `removeFromSuperView` method

`[typeCollectionView removeFromSuperView]`

The code you are using just sets the outlet to `nil` it doesn't remove the view from view hierarchy

If your outlet is a weak property/reference then you just have to call `removeFromSuperView`. But if its a strong one then you should also set the outlet to `nil`.

Comment: So I need to do both ?